# Primereact InputNumber ref

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Am I just blind and don't see it anywhere but is it not possible to have a ref={name} on a InputNumber element?

```
<InputNumber
  type="tel"
  value={selectedData.fooAmount}
  placeholder={t('dialog.foo_amount')}
  ref={fooAmountRef}
/>
```

wanted to access the value from the input elsewhere, trying this, probably not best approach intentionally, yet was surprised to see that ref is not available here. Also looking for other approaches on how to access this element without setStates and saving onChange.

Answer (score 0):

You want `inputRef` see: https://primereact.org/inputnumber/#api.InputNumber.props.inputRef

That gives you a ref to the actual input box.